# Excel - paste *only* number formatting

Tags: microsoft-excel, formatting, copy-paste, text-formatting, cell-format

Is it possible to copy/paste *only* number formatting in Excel.

There are various paste special options.

In particular Formulas/Number Formats and Values/Number Formats. But is there a way to paste only the number formatting?

Often, I’ll already have values/formats that I don’t want to paste over. And it’s just the custom number formatting I want to change.

I know you can do it in VBA, but I’m looking for a non-VBA solution or confirmation that there isn’t one.

————

Apparently I wasn’t clear enough.

I want to paste **only** the number formatting. No fonts, no colours, no borders. No other formatting of any kind.

So no paste special -> format. No format painter. Nothing that would over-ride what’s already there.

Comment: There are a number of ways to past *value* only, but the easiest is to format the cell range into which you wish to copy as numeric only. Define the number format for the columns or rows with the format you wish, including number of decimal places, thousands separator and color for negative values.

Comment: (after copy) r-click > paste special > formatting | ref : https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/paste-options-8ea795b0-87cd-46af-9b59-ed4d8b1669ad

Comment: @p._phidot_ I specifically **do not** want to copy any other formatting. Just the number formats.

Comment: hurm.. tried "Shortcuts for number formats" ? [ref : https://exceljet.net/articles/custom-number-formats ]

Comment: Have you already tried using Format Painter? If yes, why don't you want to use it? For me, it is the solution to your issue.

Comment: It sounds like you'll need VBA.. Internet searches will probably lead you to codes you can modify and where/how to store that code (hint: choices should be as an add-in or as a personal.xlsm). Good luck.

Comment: Are you looking for formula to extract numbers?

Comment: Should u had found a suitable way to do it.. Hope u didn't mind to share.. (I'm all ears..)